# Ascending & descending posts on same page with IF statement

Tags: query, order, sort

I need to be able to display a list of events on 1 page. The top list would be for upcoming events and to be sorted with earliest event first and the second list would be for expired/past events and be sorted with the latest event on top.

Example:
Upcoming event

- Event A   •  July 30, 2015
- Event Z   •  September 2, 2015
- Event G  •  December 9, 2015

Past Events

- Event F    •  June 29, 2015
- Event X    •  May 5, 2015
- Event D   •   February , 2015

I can't figure out how to change the **orderby** value from **DESC** to **ASC** within the IF statement that checks if end date is expired.

My code is as follow:

```
//GET THE CURRENT DATE
$current_date = date('F j, Y');
$current_date = strtotime( $current_date );

$args = array(      
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'event',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

// BUILD SHORTCODE CODE TO BE INSERTED
foreach($posts as $post){       

    $event_start_date=get_post_meta($post->ID,'event-start-date');
    $event_end_date=get_post_meta($post->ID,'event-end-date');

    $event_start=date('F j, Y', $event_start_date[0]);
    $event_end=date('F j, Y', $event_end_date[0]);
    $exp_date = strtotime( $event_end );

    if( $exp_date > $current_date ) {

    $shortcode_str="[MY_SHORTCODE_CURRENT]";
    } 
    else {
    $shortcode_str_ex="[MY_SHORTCODE_EXPIRED]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the `DESC` to `ASC` "within the IF statement". The query has already ran at that point. I don't really understand what the code is meant to do though. I don't really see that code ever producing the pattern you describe. Specifically, I don't understand what the shortcode strings or for or how that is supposed to work. However, I can duplicate the result. Maybe that will help.

```
//GET THE CURRENT DATE
$current_date = date('F j, Y');
$current_date = strtotime( $current_date );

$args = array(      
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

$expired = array();

// BUILD SHORTCODE CODE TO BE INSERTED
foreach($posts as $post){       
  $event_start_date=get_post_meta($post->ID,'event-start-date',true);
  $event_end_date=get_post_meta($post->ID,'event-end-date',true);

  if (empty($event_start_date) || empty($event_end_date)) continue;
  $event_start=date('F j, Y', $event_start_date);
  $event_end=date('F j, Y', $event_end_date);
  $exp_date = strtotime( $event_end );

  echo '$exp_date > $current_date<br>';
  if( $exp_date > $current_date ) {
    // Match:
    // Event A • July 30, 2015 
    echo the_title(),' &bull; ',$event_end;
    echo '<br>';
  } 
  else {
    array_unshift($expired, get_the_title().' &bull; '.$event_end);
  }
}
echo '$expired<br>';
if (!empty($expired)) {
  echo implode('<br>',$expired);
}
```

Note: Without going through a bunch of posts and setting the meta fields, which would be tedious, I can't test this but I have a fair certainty that that is on the right track.

Edit: I did clean up the code a little but it essentially does work. `array_unshift` **prepends** items to an array so if the original items are sorted `DESC` then the array created by `array_unshift` should be the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but the code doesn't seem to take in account the "sorting" part?

Comment: Ok. You are going to force me to do the tedious :)

Comment: The second sorting is done by `array_unshift`. See the edit.

Comment: Yes, very sorry, I didn't get that. I will try this approach and let you know!